# Reading number from file into variable -- How to put a number into my document that increments with every compilation?

Tags: programming, write-file

I am not that much into TeX/LaTex programming ...

but what I want to do is the following:

**How to put a number into my document that increments with every compilation**

My ideas so far are:

- use a text file as storage of the number
- read in the number
- add 1
- save the number to the text file
- put the number into the text

I was able to use something like this :

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\newwrite\tempfile
\begin{document}
\immediate\openout\tempfile=lists.tex
\immediate\write\tempfile{1}
\immediate\closeout\tempfile
\input{lists}
\end{document}
```

([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2115412/1144966)) to write to a file but did not manage to read the number from the file into a variable that than could be iterated by one and saved back to the file. Does anyone has an idea?

Comment: It should be pointed out that the file with the number should be read *before* you write a number to it. The `\immediate\openout` command immediately overwrites whatever was in the file beforehand. David's answer uses the `.aux` file, which is input at the beginning of `\begin{document}`'s code, before material added by `\AtBeginDocument`. A second point: it is easiest to write the full definition to the external file (as in David's answer), and then just input it to get the macro defined.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the package `totcount`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{totcount}

\newtotcounter{compilation}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setcounter{compilation}{\value{compilation@totc}}%
  % when the aux file doesn't yet exist the value is -1
  % so we fix it
  \ifnum\value{compilation}=-1 \setcounter{compilation}{0}\fi
  \stepcounter{compilation}%
}

\begin{document}

This is \LaTeX{} run number \thecompilation.

\end{document}
```

This will however restart from 1 if the `.aux` file is removed or gets corrupted. You can use, instead, a different file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{compilation}
\newwrite\writecompilation
\newread\readcompilation
\openin\readcompilation=\jobname.vrs
\ifeof\readcompilation
  % no file yet
  \setcounter{compilation}{1}%
\else
  \read\readcompilation to \temp
  \setcounter{compilation}{\temp}%
  \stepcounter{compilation}%
\fi
\closein\readcompilation
\immediate\openout\writecompilation=\jobname.vrs
\immediate\write\writecompilation{\thecompilation}
\immediate\closeout\writecompilation

\begin{document}

This is \LaTeX{} run number \thecompilation.

\end{document}
```

If nothing goes wrong, the file with the same name as the main file and extension `.vrs` will contain the number of the most recent run.

Answer (score 8):

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
\ifx\mynum\@undefined\def\mynum{0}\fi
\edef\mynum{\the\numexpr\mynum + 1\relax}%
\immediate\write\@auxout{\gdef\string\mynum{\mynum}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

[\mynum]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, nice, this uses the ``.aux`` file to store the value. But when the .aux is deleted, the version number is lost - right? Is it possible to use another file for storage?

Comment: Yes but you shouldn't delete the aux file, you could save it in a .foo file but if you delete that you'd have the same problem. You need to read the old file, close it then re-open for writing, it's easier with aux as latex is doing that anyway. To use another one I'd probably use `\@starttoc{foo}` which is the helper macro behind toc for table of contents and lof for list of figures etc. But personally I'd use aux