# Set counter to a value written in another file

Tags: counters, external-files

I got a file 'month.tex' containing only an integer. I want to set a counter to this integer and tried

```
\newcounter{billmonth}
\setcounter{billmonth}{\input{month.tex}}
```

This isn't working as the compiler sais

```
<to be read again> 
\let 
l.42 \setcounter{billmonth}{\input{month.tex}}
```

Does anybode have an idea how to deal with this? Thanks!

Why do I have a file containing only this integer? I use a bash script for compiling where you can pass an argument. This argument needs to find its way inside of my latex document and it was the best way i could think of.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321346/how-to-read-a-variable-from-a-file-in-latex, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187878/reading-number-from-file-into-variable-how-to-put-a-number-into-my-document-t

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `readarray` package can help, with its `\readdef{<filename>}\macro` syntax.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}% this is only to show that it works
\begin{filecontents*}{monthfile}
 3
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{readarray}
\readdef{monthfile}\thereadmonth
\newcounter{billmonth}
\setcounter{billmonth}{\thereadmonth}
\begin{document}
\thebillmonth
\end{document}
```